# How can I write an SQL query to join two tables aggregating some rows?

Tags: sql

Let's say there is a table for credit and debit transactions in a bank account, e.g.

**Transaction**

| Category | DebitCredit | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Food | Debit | 10 |
| Gifts | Credit | 30 |
| Books | Debit | 20 |
| Cash | Debit | 300 |

and another table for transactions made by cash, e.g.

**CashTransaction**

| Category | DebitCredit | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Drinks | Debit | 10 |
| Food | Debit | 30 |

I want to join them such that the new table:

1. Contains distinct category per row, with amounts added up (or subtracted if transaction was credit) for the category.
2. All the transactions from CashTransaction table are subtracted from "Cash" category, since they are listed as separate categories in the join.

Expected result:

| Category | DebitCredit | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Food | Debit | 40 |
| Gifts | Credit | 30 |
| Books | Debit | 20 |
| Drinks | Debit | 10 |
| Cash | Debit | 260 |

How can this be done in a single query? Or is there a better way to structure the tables to achieve this?

I'm using H2, but any SQL dialect will do.

Comment: `select q.category,q.debitcredit,sum(q.amount) from (select  q1.category,q1debitcredit,q1.amount from table1 as q1 union all select  q2.category,q2debitcredit,q2.amount from table2 as q2 ) as q group by q.category,q.debitcredit`

Comment: Thanks, @Nathan_Sav, but it doesn't subtract cash transactions (second table) from the "Cash" category (see my requirement 2), which is the most tricky part here. Also, it would list the same category twice if it had both credit and debit transactions.

Comment: You will need to substitute the `category` field for static `'Cash'` in the query for the cash table be it table1 or table2

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Ohh, that's a nice trick. :) I think I can use it.